# download files when user press back or close the app and restart the app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am very new to iOS and I want to download the database from the server in iOS App. It works perfectly first time when i run the app from Xcode in simulator.

After download is finished,I pressed <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the home screen, as there is no home/back button in the simulator. Again I opened the app but it doesn't download the database this time.

I have kept the download code in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` both and its downloading the db twice at the same time.

My purpose is to download the file when user resumes/restart the app. I have done same thing in android, where `onResume`/`onPause`/`onRestart` methods are available. I want to achieve the same thing ion iOS also.

One doubt......

1. How to press back button in iOS simulator?

I think back button starts the app from start (At least in android) not home button. How can I test this in iOS simulator.

Comment: I'd like to suggest an alternative solution as the one you have said sounds pretty poor. Why not download the Database when the user opens the app and cache that data, storing the data of last download. Whilst in your database every time you make a change add a last update field. So when the user restarts the app you can check the locally stored data against the database and if last updated in the database is after the local last updated then download the new data. This will save on network usage and overall offer a better user experience as it will be faster.

Comment: Also I'd probably have this in the app delegate somewhere for checking when the app starts up and not in `viewWillAppear` and/or `viewDidLoad`. Possibly in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: same thing i have planned to do...but for now i just want to test whether app downloads the data when it resume or restarts.....application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions does it get called when user close the app and again restart or resume it.

Comment: It all depends on how you have done your app. If you have done it so it never runs in the background and will always start up as if it was a fresh instance then yes `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will always get called. But if your app can go into background mode and start up from where it closed then no this isn't always called and you will need to have a look at something like `applicationDidBecomeActive:` so you capture it when it becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

- If you really need to download your data **every time** the view is shown (I really don't recommend this), remove the download code from `viewDidLoad` and keep the one from `viewWillAppear`.
- `command+shift+H` is the right way to press the home button on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle application states. refer below document from apple -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

handle those from appDelegate or

You can handle those by adding the observers like below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(backgroundMethod)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(foregroundMethod)
                                                name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                              object:nil];
```